# Custom SQL Query to Count by Range or Group

Tags: sql

In this example, how do I return the count of employees by salary band using SQL?

```
Table : EmployeeSalary
Employee Salary
1        21,000
2        24,000
3        30,000
4        31,000
5        32,000
6        50,000

Table: SalaryBands
ID Name  MinSalary MaxSalary
1  Tier1 20,000    24,999
2  Tier2 25,000    44,999
3  Tier3 45,000    150,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select s.name, count(*) as count
from employeesalary e
inner join salarybands s on e.salary >= s.minsalary and e.salary <=s.maxsalary
group by s.name
```

The key idea is to join the tables based on which salary range each employee's salary falls in. The counting is then implemented in the usual way.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KRB76306)

Answer (score 0):

A nonequi join is a perfect fit for your needs. It's a join that does not use equivalence operator to match rows.

```
SELECT
  sb.name,
  count(*)
FROM
  EmployeeSalary es
  INNER JOIN SalaryBands sb ON
    es.salary BETWEEN sb.minsalary AND sb.maxsalary
GROUP BY sb.name
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method that requires no joins.

```
select 
sum(case when REPLACE(salary, ',', '') between 20000 and 24999) then 1 else 0 end as count_tier1,
sum(case when REPLACE(salary, ',', '') between 25000 and 44999) then 1 else 0 end as count_tier2,
sum(case when REPLACE(salary, ',', '') between 45000 and 150000) then 1 else 0 end as count_tier3
from
Employee_salary
;
```